# prevent duplicate insert by using updatepanel

Tags: c#, insert, updatepanel

i wrote a page which are several fields and there is gridview which keeps the data inserted bottom of the page and i added a updatepanel... when i click the insert double data inserting to grid how to prevent it...

Answer (score 0):

1. Disable the button that users have to click to insert data to the grid.
2. Clear all the input fields.